# An item with the same key has already been added .Net native tool chain

Tags: compiler-errors, uwp, .net-native

[UWP][PCL]

Hi all,

When building in release mode (with .NET Native tool chain enabled), I have the following error from compiler :

**An item with the same key has already been added**

I tried to get diagnostic log, but it does not help.
I've already cleaned my Nugget cache, deleted obj&bin folders, tried as administrator, upgrade VS to the last version (15.8.1)

Packages used are :

```
'GalaSoft.MvvmLight'
'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras'
'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation'
'Newtonsoft.Json'
'PCLStorage'
'PCLStorage.Abastractions'
'System.Net.Http.Formatting'
'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract'
```

None of my own packages are starting with the samename.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Unfortunaly, not... Problem seems to come from my PCL... The error message is not very usefull :(

Comment: If you could not provide a simple code sample, it's hard to help you diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Found !

In the constructor of ONE ViewModel, I was using "IsInDesignModeStatic" (from MVVM Light), by changing it to "IsInDesignMode", no more problem.

Thanks all for helping.